# HttpClient on Xamarin.Forms Android Not Responding and Freezing (Prism)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpclient, prism

I have a very simple MVVM application using Xamrin Forms and Prism, built from the Prism Xamarin Template.

When I initialize a new ViewModel I am trying to make a call to an API, on UWP this is working without any issues but on Android it is just freezing and not returning any errors or throwing any exceptions.

I have simplified the code down to where the error is happening and tested with a URI that anyone can use.

```
public async Task InitializeAsync(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.co.uk").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am using the below NuGets

- Prism.Core v8.0.0.1909
- Prism.Dryloc.Forms v8.0.0.1909
- Xamarin.Forms v4.8.0.1687

I have set the HttpClient implementation to Android and Native TLS 1.2+
[image]

I have reviewed several other posts that seem similar but have had no joy in fixing the issue, can anyone shed any light on how I can troubleshoot this or get it working?

Comment: Have a look at this implementation [link](https://github.com/arditmezini/api-core/blob/master/BookStore/BookStore/Repository/GenericRepository.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting this for a while and banging my head against a brick wall I've finally figured out what was going wrong.

Nothing!

Step through on Android wasn't stepping past line 7 below and the screen wasn't redrawing.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.co.uk").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When I turned my phone 90 degrees the screen would redraw and I could see that the request had worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue when I started working with Xamarin.

I have also build a library that could help you very much called [Rest.API.Translator](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5164623/Introduction-to-Rest-API-Translator)
You could find it also on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rest.API.Translator/)

Now incase you are not willing to work with my library, You could have a look at my code [here](https://github.com/AlenToma/Rest.API.Translator/blob/master/source/HttpHandler.cs) Too know how I fixed the problem with freezing issue.

Have a look at

```
Client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Await()
```

`.Await` is an extension that I created to make sure no overlapping and freezing issue is happing between the http calls

Comment: First of all thank you for responding.  It's great that you are writing a library that can be used and sharing it; however that does not answer the question of what is going wrong and how I troubleshoot it.  Do you know what the issue is or how it can be troubeshot (shooted)?